# MongoDB KeyError, No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have a query in MongoDB using Python:

```
for car in cars.find({"year": "2014"}):
    print car['V8']
```

The problem is, not every record has V8 entry exists. It will pop up error:

> KeyError: 'V8'
>
> No JSON object could be decoded

How can I ignore the error and just print empty string if the Key is not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like python, if so you can do

```
print car.get("V8", "")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it will return None. And when I concatenate the result to some other string, it shows error "TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found". Is there a workaround?

Comment: Edited. Try that, the second param to get() is what is returned when the key is not found